# Rails activerecord count number of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model called Impression - which counts the views of each Card (also a model).
I am trying to print a table with the cards, that has at least 10 views in the last month.
So I started with -

```
cards = Card.joins(:impressions).where("impressions.created_at > ? AND impressions.created_at < ?", Date.today-30.days, Date.today).uniq
```

And then I did -

```
cards.select {|card| card.impressions.count >= 10 }
```

But it runs a long long times. I want something much more efficient.
Any ideas for counting the number of impressions and sorting them?

I want to do it efficiently as I can - without iterating over the whole DB with the N+1 problem, cause it could get pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your impressions tables' created_at column have index?

If you are querying it and there is none - you could add it by generating a migration file.

```
add_index(:impressions, :created_at)
```

And you could use pure SQL to add condition to your query like:

```
cards = Card.joins(:impressions)
            .where("impressions.created_at > ? AND impressions.created_at < ?", Date.today-30.days, Date.today)
            .group('cards.id')
            .having('COUNT(impressions.*) >= 10')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.last()` function

Try this

```
cards = Card.joins(:impressions).where("impressions.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month , 1.month.ago.end_of_month).uniq.last(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use having and AREL

Try this :

```
cards = Card.joins(:impressions).where(impressions: {created_at: (Date.today-30.days..Date.today)}).having(Impressions.arel_table[:id].count.gteq(10)).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how your relations looks and the quantity of data you have. Thus assuming your relations look like

**Card**

```
class Card
  has_many :impressions
end
```

**Impression**

```
class Impression
  belongs_to :card
end
```

my suggestion is to try something like this:

```
cards_id = Card.pluck(:id)
past_one_month_impressions_arel = Impression.where("impressions.created_at > ? AND impressions.created_at < ?", Date.today-30.days, Date.today)

cards_id_having_atleast_10_views = cards_id.select do |c_id|
  arel = past_one_month_impressions_arel.where(impressions: { card_id: cid } )
  arel.count >= 10
end

cards = Card.where(id: cards_id_having_atleast_10_views)
```

Also you may try using [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) to iterate in batches if you have a lot of data.

Hope that helps.

Thanks.